# Bash needs to send a command to another CLI

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, lte

I want to automate some command the thing is we login to the server and the next commandline isn't a linux commandline but rather that of an application it self. My current attempt of solution is the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
# smsme.sh

i=0
i=$((i+1))


rancli
         sleep 3
echo `add saf dest=4949 orig=Wim text=$i`
sleep 120;

# ---
```

Quick hint it breaks on add. I tried piping the commands as well it just echoed in the linux enverimont without ever hitting the rancli

Updated scripts after update

```
#!/bin/bash
# smsme.sh

i=0
i=$((i+1))

rancli

read $reply
```

Answer script

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set timeout -1

spawn ./smsme.sh


expect {
    "Quortus Core CLI (c) 2019
    No entry for terminal type "xterm-256color";
    using dumb terminal settings.
    Connecting to RAN at 127.0.0.1:3012QCore>
    LTE64b>"

    }
    eof
}




send -- add saf dest=4949 orig=Wim text=wim

expect "Submitted, message number $1"

expect eof
```

Comment: You aren't starting `rancli` anywhere in this script.

Comment: Don't use backquotes, they're used for command substitution (the quoted part is run as a command and the output is used as the echo parameters).

Comment: Maybe you should read about [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). This tool is designed to "talk" to interactive programs.

Comment: Thx, expect seems something like what I need for this. Gonna read the manual first.

Comment: Take a look at [tag:expect] questions on the site, too, for examples.  If you solve your problem yourself, feel free to post your own answer!

Comment: @JeffSchaller & all Thx I am getting a lot closer the only thing still going wrong is patching the output to rancli. Since the output is a little too long I put in a debian [link](http://paste.debian.net/1082855/)paste[/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answers provided here and looking trough the expect questions solved it for me. I had one weird little thing where bash didn't know expect, also a fix for that in this answer. And I have another issue of not being able to increment a variable in the non Bash enverimont. But for now I can run this as cronjob

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set timeout 20

set cmd "rancli"

eval spawn $cmd
expect "Connecting to RAN at 127.0.0.1:3012QCore>"
sleep 2
send "add saf dest=8345 orig=politie text=panda\r"
expect "Submitted,"
send "exit\r"
```

If anyone has advice it would on how to change panda\r"into a variable which increments ( +1) it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above expect can do this call you are attempting. Based on this other application cli interface response you can interact with it.

```
VAR=$(expect -c "
  spawn rancli add saf dest=4949 org=Wim text=$i 
  expect \"place_what_expect_to_receive_from_that_appcli\"
  send \"whatever_you_want_to_send_initially\r\"
  expect \"\\\\example_system_cursor \"
  #you can sleep if needed
  sleep 2
")
```

Comment: just before you commented I added some extra info in a debian paste [link](http://paste.debian.net/1082855/) I have a couple ways I could implemant this right now. But I am unsure what's the best way, I am still not able to get the send right so far. rancli is the spawn the send is add saf dest4949 org=Wim text=$1 (should be a variable that counts up)